# libgluezilla for Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: software-installation, mono

`libgluezilla` doesn't seem to be available anymore. This breaks a few Mono apps on Ubuntu.

Where can I get it? `libmono-webbrowser4.0-cil` is installed, but it doesn't install `libgluezilla`.

Answer (score 2):

The latest version was for Lucid, but you can install the package also in Vivid with some aditionally packages.

- Download the Lucid version of `libgluezilla_2.4.3-2`

  - 32-bit

    ```
    cd; wget http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gluezilla/libgluezilla_2.4.3-2_i386.deb
    ```

    **OR**
  - 64-bit

    ```
    cd; wget http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gluezilla/libgluezilla_2.4.3-2_amd64.deb
    ```
- Download `xulrunner-1.9.2`

  - 32-bit

    ```
    cd; wget http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/x/xulrunner-1.9.2/xulrunner-1.9.2_1.9.2.28+build1+nobinonly-0ubuntu0.10.04.1_i386.deb
    ```

    **OR**
  - 64-bit

    ```
    cd; wget http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/x/xulrunner-1.9.2/xulrunner-1.9.2_1.9.2.28+build1+nobinonly-0ubuntu0.10.04.1_amd64.deb
    ```
- Download `libhunspell-1.2-0`

  - 32-bit

    ```
    cd; wget http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/h/hunspell/libhunspell-1.2-0_1.2.8-6ubuntu1_i386.deb
    ```

    **OR**
  - 64-bit

    ```
    cd; wget http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/h/hunspell/libhunspell-1.2-0_1.2.8-6ubuntu1_amd64.deb
    ```
- Install dependencies available in the repositories (perhaps more depends on your current installation)

  ```
  sudo apt-get install libnspr4-0d libidl0 libnss3-1d
  ```
- Install

  - 32-bit

    ```
    sudo dpkg -i libgluezilla_2.4.3-2_i386.deb xulrunner-1.9.2_1.9.2.28+build1+nobinonly-0ubuntu0.10.04.1_i386.deb libhunspell-1.2-0_1.2.8-6ubuntu1_i386.deb
    ```

    **OR**
  - 64-bit

    ```
    sudo dpkg -i libgluezilla_2.4.3-2_amd64.deb xulrunner-1.9.2_1.9.2.28+build1+nobinonly-0ubuntu0.10.04.1_amd64.deb libhunspell-1.2-0_1.2.8-6ubuntu1_amd64.deb
    ```

---

*Tested in my Vivid system*

```
% lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 15.04
Release:    15.04
Codename:   vivid

% apt-cache policy libgluezilla 
libgluezilla:
  Installed: 2.4.3-2
  Candidate: 2.4.3-2
  Version table:
 *** 2.4.3-2 0
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Comment: Your last command is missing the 'l' for lib...

Comment: libidl0 and libnss3-1d was also needed

Comment: I got a SIGSEGV, but the packages installed successfully. I guess the libc and some others may have changed since lucid.

Comment: that's not really fair. your question has been answered. for new problems you should ask a new question.

Comment: I believe your solution to installing the package is pointless if it doesn't work. The question is specifically for Vivid so the package should be functional there as well.

Comment: All the URLs are dead. Are there newer URLs that still work?

Answer (score 1):

The solution provided by A.B. works fine for 16.04.2 but note that when installing the libidl0 using apt-get, it will require libidl-2-0. A solution to install libidl0 on Ubuntu 16.04 is here: [Unable to install Kompozer in Ubuntu 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/832913/unable-to-install-kompozer-in-ubuntu-16-04?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)
After libidl0 is installed. Follow A.B.'s steps and it works!!

For 14.04, it seems it does not work as the xulrunner cannot be installed. Still figuring out how it can be done correctly.

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial

$ apt-cache policy libgluezillalibgluezilla:
  Installed: 2.4.3-2
  Candidate: 2.4.3-2
  Version table:
 *** 2.4.3-2 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```