# Unable to install Kompozer in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, software-installation, kompozer

I got the following error message when trying to install Kompozer in Ubuntu 16.04.

```
saraswati@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get install libatk1.0-0 libc6 libcairo2 libfontconfig1 libfreetype6 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 libglib2.0-0 libgtk2.0-0 libidl0 libnspr4 libnss3 libpango1.0-0 libpng12-0 libstdc++6 libx11-6 libxft2 libxinerama1 libxrender1 libxt6 zlib1g  
Reading package lists... Done  
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information... Done  
Package libidl0 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
  libidl-2-0:i386 libidl-2-0

E: Package 'libidl0' has no installation candidate
```

Please help me to sort out this problem.

Comment: what happens if you use this command curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php

Answer (score 9, accepted):

kompozer is a native snap package in all currently supported versions of Ubuntu. This snap package preserves the last available version of KompoZer from 2010, and allows KompoZer to be used on modern operating systems. KompoZer can be installed from the Software app or from the terminal with the following command:

```
sudo snap install kompozer
```

---

The kompozer snap packager was not in the Snap Store when Ubuntu 16.04 was a supported release, so this was how to install KompoZer in Ubuntu 16.04 instead. Install the same packages you tried to install before except for libidl0. Open the terminal and type:

#### Ubuntu 16.04

```
sudo apt install libatk1.0-0 libc6 libcairo2 libfontconfig1 libfreetype6 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 libglib2.0-0 libgtk2.0-0 libnspr4 libnss3 libpango1.0-0 libstdc++-5-dev libx11-6 libxft2 libxinerama1 libxrender1 libxt6 zlib1g
```

- 32-Bit:

  ```
   wget https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+files/kompozer-data_0.8%7Eb3.dfsg.1-0.1ubuntu2_all.deb
   wget https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+files/kompozer_0.8%7Eb3.dfsg.1-0.1ubuntu2_i386.deb
   wget https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+files/libidl0_0.8.14-1_i386.deb
   sudo apt install ./libidl0_0.8.14-1_i386.deb
   sudo apt install ./kompozer-data_0.8~b3.dfsg.1-0.1ubuntu2_all.deb
   sudo apt install ./kompozer_0.8~b3.dfsg.1-0.1ubuntu2_i386.deb
  ```
- 64-Bit:

  ```
   wget https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+files/kompozer-data_0.8%7Eb3.dfsg.1-0.1ubuntu2_all.deb
   wget https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+files/kompozer_0.8%7Eb3.dfsg.1-0.1ubuntu2_amd64.deb
   wget https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+files/libidl0_0.8.14-1_amd64.deb
   sudo apt install ./libidl0_0.8.14-1_amd64.deb
   sudo apt install ./kompozer-data_0.8~b3.dfsg.1-0.1ubuntu2_all.deb
   sudo apt install ./kompozer_0.8~b3.dfsg.1-0.1ubuntu2_amd64.deb
  ```

#### Ubuntu 18.04-19.04

```
sudo apt install libatk1.0-0 libc6 libcairo2 libfontconfig1 libfreetype6 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 libglib2.0-0 libgtk2.0-0 libnspr4 libnss3 libpango1.0-0 libstdc++-6-dev libx11-6 libxft2 libxinerama1 libxrender1 libxt6 zlib1g
```

- 32-Bit:

  ```
  wget https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+files/kompozer-data_0.8%7Eb3.dfsg.1-0.1ubuntu2_all.deb
  wget https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+files/kompozer_0.8%7Eb3.dfsg.1-0.1ubuntu2_i386.deb
  wget https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+files/libidl0_0.8.14-1_i386.deb
  wget https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+files/libpng12-0_1.2.54-1ubuntu1_i386.deb  
  sudo apt install ./libidl0_0.8.14-1_i386.deb  
  sudo apt install ./libpng12-0_1.2.54-1ubuntu1_i386.deb
  sudo apt install ./kompozer-data_0.8~b3.dfsg.1-0.1ubuntu2_all.deb
  sudo apt install ./kompozer_0.8~b3.dfsg.1-0.1ubuntu2_i386.deb
  ```
- 64-Bit:

  ```
  wget https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+files/kompozer-data_0.8%7Eb3.dfsg.1-0.1ubuntu2_all.deb
  wget https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+files/kompozer_0.8%7Eb3.dfsg.1-0.1ubuntu2_amd64.deb
  wget https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+files/libidl0_0.8.14-1_amd64.deb  
  wget https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+files/libpng12-0_1.2.54-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb  
  sudo apt install ./libidl0_0.8.14-1_amd64.deb  
  sudo apt install ./libpng12-0_1.2.54-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb
  sudo apt install ./kompozer-data_0.8~b3.dfsg.1-0.1ubuntu2_all.deb
  sudo apt install ./kompozer_0.8~b3.dfsg.1-0.1ubuntu2_amd64.deb
  ```

#### Ubuntu 19.10-20.04

```
sudo apt install libatk1.0-0 libc6 libcairo2 libfontconfig1 libfreetype6 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 libglib2.0-0 libgtk2.0-0 libnspr4 libnss3 libpango1.0-0 libstdc++-7-dev libx11-6 libxft2 libxinerama1 libxrender1 libxt6 zlib1g 
wget https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+files/kompozer-data_0.8%7Eb3.dfsg.1-0.1ubuntu2_all.deb
wget https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+files/kompozer_0.8%7Eb3.dfsg.1-0.1ubuntu2_amd64.deb
wget https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+files/libidl0_0.8.14-1_amd64.deb  
wget https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+files/libpng12-0_1.2.54-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb 
wget http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/glibc/multiarch-support_2.27-3ubuntu1.2_amd64.deb  
sudo apt install ./libidl0_0.8.14-1_amd64.deb ./libpng12-0_1.2.54-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb ./kompozer-data_0.8~b3.dfsg.1-0.1ubuntu2_all.deb ./kompozer_0.8~b3.dfsg.1-0.1ubuntu2_amd64.deb ./multiarch-support_2.27-3ubuntu1.2_amd64.deb
```

Answer (score 2):

Above answer for Ubuntu 16.04 64-bit no longer works. Problem on `sudo dpkg -i libidl0_0.8.14-1_amd64.deb`:

```
john@Laptop:~/Software/Kompozer$ sudo dpkg -i libidl0_0.8.14-1_amd64.deb
[sudo] password for john: 
Selecting previously unselected package libidl0:amd64.
(Reading database ... 366612 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack libidl0_0.8.14-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libidl0:amd64 (0.8.14-1) ...
Replaced by files in installed package libidl-2-0:amd64 (0.8.14-4) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libidl0:amd64:
 libidl-2-0:amd64 (0.8.14-4) breaks libidl0 (<< 0.8.14-3) and is installed.
  Version of libidl0:amd64 to be configured is 0.8.14-1.

dpkg: error processing package libidl0:amd64 (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libidl0:amd64
```

Solved by:

```
sudo apt-get -f install
sudo apt-get remove libidl-2-0
sudo dpkg -i libidl0_0.8.14-1_amd64.deb
```

and then as before.

Answer (score 0):

Problem referred to in my Comment on not working for 16.04 has been rectified in 18.04. However, on new installation of 18.04, am now getting:

```
john@JohnPC:~/Software/Kompozer$ sudo dpkg -i kompozer_0.8~b3.dfsg.1-0.1ubuntu2_amd64.deb 
Selecting previously unselected package kompozer.
(Reading database ... 264748 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack kompozer_0.8~b3.dfsg.1-0.1ubuntu2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking kompozer (1:0.8~b3.dfsg.1-0.1ubuntu2) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of kompozer:
 kompozer depends on libpango1.0-0 (>= 1.14.0); however:
  Package libpango1.0-0 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package kompozer (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for man-db (2.8.3-2) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.13.3-11ubuntu1.1) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.23-1ubuntu3.18.04.1) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.60ubuntu1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 kompozer
```

This error is rectified by:

```
sudo apt install libpango1.0-0
```

followed by:

```
sudo dpkg -i kompozer_0.8~b3.dfsg.1-0.1ubuntu2_amd64.deb
```

Answer (score 0):

As of June 2020, you can install Kompozer on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS (32-bit) with the following steps:

#### Step 1

Open a terminal and enter this command to install dependencies:

```
sudo apt-get install libatk1.0-0 libc6 libcairo2 libfontconfig1 \
libfreetype6 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 libglib2.0-0 libgtk2.0-0  libidl-2-0 \
libnspr4 libnss3 libpango1.0-0 libpng12-0 libstdc++6 libx11-6 libxft2 \
libxinerama1 libxrender1 libxt6 zlib1g
```

#### Step 2

**For 32-bit systems**:

```
wget https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+files/kompozer-data_0.8%7Eb3.dfsg.1-0.1ubuntu2_all.deb
wget https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+files/kompozer_0.8%7Eb3.dfsg.1-0.1ubuntu2_i386.deb
sudo dpkg -i kompozer-data_0.8~b3.dfsg.1-0.1ubuntu2_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i kompozer_0.8~b3.dfsg.1-0.1ubuntu2_i386.deb
```

**For 64-bit systems**:

```
wget https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+files/kompozer-data_0.8%7Eb3.dfsg.1-0.1ubuntu2_all.deb
wget https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+files/kompozer_0.8%7Eb3.dfsg.1-0.1ubuntu2_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i kompozer-data_0.8~b3.dfsg.1-0.1ubuntu2_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i kompozer_0.8~b3.dfsg.1-0.1ubuntu2_amd64.deb
```

Kompozer should now be properly installed!