# Installing Kompozer in Ubuntu Budgie 19.04

Tags: package-management, dpkg, dependencies, kompozer

I'm not an experienced user, so please bear with me. I've been trying to install Kompozer from two different sources, but none of them worked.

First, I downloaded a .deb file from here (https://download.cnet.com/KompoZer-for-Debian-and-Ubuntu/3000-10247_4-75219243.html), but my package installer was unable to install it. The dpkg command didn't work neither. When I run *sudo dpkg -i /home/jesus/Downloads/kompozer_0.8_b3.dfsg.1-0.1ubuntu2_amd64.deb*, I get the following:

```
(Reading database ... 255283 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../kompozer_0.8_b3.dfsg.1-0.1ubuntu2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking kompozer (1:0.8~b3.dfsg.1-0.1ubuntu2) over (1:0.8~b3.dfsg.1-0.1ubuntu2) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of kompozer:
 kompozer depends on libpng12-0 (>= 1.2.13-4); however:
  Package libpng12-0:amd64 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package kompozer (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for man-db (2.8.5-2) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.32.0-1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.23-4ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon (0.5.3+18.04.20180207.2-0ubuntu1) ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.60ubuntu1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 kompozer
```

I tried to install the libpng12-0 from (https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/amd64/libpng12-0/download); However, I got another problem:

```
(Reading database ... 255283 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libpng12-0_1.2.54-1ubuntu1.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libpng12-0:amd64 (1.2.54-1ubuntu1.1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /home/jesus/Downloads/libpng12-0_1.2.54-1ubuntu1.1_amd64.deb (--install):
 unable to install new version of '/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng12.so.0': No such file or directory
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.29-0ubuntu2) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /home/jesus/Downloads/libpng12-0_1.2.54-1ubuntu1.1_amd64.deb
```

Then, I tried this PPA (https://launchpad.net/~giuseppe-iuculano/+archive/ubuntu/ppa), but it also fails. When I type "sudo apt-get install kompozer", I get the following:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
kompozer is already the newest version (1:0.8~b3.dfsg.1-0.1ubuntu2).
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 kompozer : Depends: libpng12-0 (>= 1.2.13-4) but it is not installable
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

I have seen a few answers on this site to people having similar problems with the installation of Kompozer, but they didn't work for me.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you installing package with `dpkg`, it just installs this package, when **all requirement are met**. It does not look around, how to install those dependencies you may need for particular package. So one way (hard) is to make sure which packages your wanted package additionally need and download them an install them first.

Easier way is to do like you did and afterwards run one command (as suggested in your output, too):

```
sudo apt --fix-broken install
```

Anyway, your output also says:

```
kompozer is already the newest version (1:0.8~b3.dfsg.1-0.1ubuntu2)
```

I have no idea, is this really newest version (and version you need), but it seems somehow already installed. If you tried from multiple sources, there may be something still wrong, running command from above should fix this (most times).

**Edit**

You stucked and `fix-broken` won't help. So, my solution would be to remove kompozer from system completely, like:

```
sudo apt purge kompozer
```

and then try to install it already from repo:

```
sudo apt install kompozer
```

**Edit2**

After closer look to Kompozer I must tell: this software is so old, that it may be too hard to ran on such a new system, it depends on libraries from Ubuntu 12.04 or older. Maybe it is simpler to run it with older Ubuntu?

Comment: When I run sudo apt --fix-broken install, I get the following: https://pastebin.com/HKtDKXYU and it looks pretty much like it got removed...

Comment: Ok, did not notice it, sorry. So you have mixed two paths, from file and from repo together. I try to address your situation in my answer.

Comment: After the purge command, when I type "sudo apt install kompozer" I get this output: https://pastebin.com/7hZYuVTs I tried re-adding the PPA and trying again, but didn't work

Comment: @JesúsLencina With command `ls -la /etc/apt/sources.list.d/` you can list which additional repos (PPAs) you have besides official. Do you see a file there, which may refer to needed PPA?

Comment: The word Giuseppe (which is the name of the PPA) appears in two lines... All the sources look to appear twice though... Here's a picture https://i.imgur.com/gj0tYDi.png

Comment: @JesúsLencina I looked into PPA, it says, supported Ubuntus are "hardy, intrepid,jaunty", it makes it about 10 years ago. I'm sure that there is way to get it work somehow, but is it worth? Have you familiar with this: https://askubuntu.com/a/876859/10577 If I really needed this software, I would install older Ubuntu and use it there.

Comment: I see... I knew it was discountinued, but didn't imagine it would be that old. I have another machine running an older version of Ubuntu (not sure which), but I'll give it a try there. If still not working, I'm probably using a VM. Anyway, Thanks!