# I can not install Kompozer on ubuntu 19.04

Tags: downloads, kompozer

I use Ubuntu 19.04 and I want to get Kompozer. I Searched for a long time, but all download - links are death or do not work. Can someone send me a download link, wich I can download and install Kompozer? It is also good, if I have to use Terminal.

Yours Ubuntu User

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to install Kompozer in Ubuntu 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/832913/unable-to-install-kompozer-in-ubuntu-16-04) The accepted answer is updated to 19.10.

Comment: I think [Seamonkey](https://www.seamonkey-project.org/) does what Kompozer did and more.

Comment: thank you very much. It is not the same as Kompozer, but It is better, than downloads, wich doesent work.